# Why are the selection principle $S_\text{fin}(\Lambda, \Omega)$ and $S_\text{fin}(\mathcal{O},\Lambda)$ impossible for nontrivial spaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology, selection-principles

Recall that an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ is a $\gamma$-cover if it is infinite and each $x\in X$ belongs to all but finitely many elements of $\mathcal{U}$ and an open open cover $\mathcal{V}$ of $X$ is large if for each $x\in X$, the set $\{V\in\mathcal{V}:x\in V\}$ is infinite. It is denoted by $\mathcal{O}$ the collection of all open covers of $X$, by $\Gamma$ the collection of all $\gamma$-covers of $X$ and by $\Lambda$ the collection of all large covers of $X$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be collections of families of sets. Then, the following selection principles are defined as follows:

$\mathbf{S_1(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})}$: For each sequence $\{A_n:n\in\omega\}$ of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ there is a sequence $\{b_n:n\in\omega\}$ such that for each $n\in\omega$, $b_n\in A_n$ and $\{b_n:n\in\omega\}$ is an element of $\mathcal{B}$.

$\mathbf{S_\text{fin}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})}$: For each sequence $\{A_n:n\in\omega\}$ of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ there is a sequence $\{B_n:n\in\omega\}$ such that for each $n\in\omega$, $B_n\in [A_n]^{<\omega}$ and $\bigcup\{B_n:n\in\omega\}$ is an element of $\mathcal{B}$.

In the paper **The combinatorics of open covers II**, the authors say that $S_\text{fin}(\Lambda, \Omega)$ and $S_\text{fin}(\mathcal{O},\Lambda)$ are impossible for nontrivial spaces $X$ and the same follows for $S_1(\Lambda, \Omega)$ and $S_1(\mathcal{O},\Lambda)$. I wonder what would be an easy example showing those claims. Thanks ahead for any help to clarify those statements.

Answer (score 2):

This is because $S_1(A,B)$ implies $S_{fin}(A,B)$, which in turn implies the property "A choose B": Every element of A contains an element of B.

Every reasonable space has an open cover that is not large, and a
large cover that is not an $\omega$-cover.